# Adding ChildClass object to ArrayList<BaseClass>

Tags: java, inheritance, arraylist

If we have a `User` base class with properties `username` and `password`.

And a child class `SpecialUser`, with an extra property `special`.

I know I can declare `ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();` and then add `SpecialUser` object to `users`, but I can only access the properties inherited from base class (`username` and `password`) that way.

Is there a way to add a `SpecialUser` to the ArrayList and be able to access `special` property? Or should they be stored seperately?

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you absolutely can!

Just after you get the object, **cast** it to SpecialUser:

```
SpecialUser spUser = (SpecialUser) users.get(0);
```

If you are not sure if the User is SpecialUser, test it before:

```
if (users.get(0) instanceof SpecialUser) {
    SpecialUser spUser = (SpecialUser) users.get(0);
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really have to, you can do it with `instanceof`:

```
User user = users.get(0);
if (user instanceof SpecialUser) {
    SpecialUser sUser = (SpecialUser) user; // class casting
    sUser.getSpecial(); // whatever subclass call you need
}
```

Do you really need this? Good polymorphism is about using the `User` -s methods and **do** something special in the subclasses.

Usually we prefer code without `instanceof`. But sometimes this is the right choice. It depends on your actual problem.